# How to get html code between two <p> tag?

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

I want get some html code between 2

tag and I have 2 regex for it

1-`$LinkGrabber = "<p><strong>item1:<\/strong> <span style=\"color: #ff0000;\"><strong>Full<\/strong><\/span><\/p>(.*)<p>&nbsp;<\/p>";`

2-`$linkGrabber = "<p><strong>item2<\/strong> <span style=\"color: #ff0000;\"><strong>Full<\/strong><\/span><\/p>(.*)<p>&nbsp;<\/p>";`

first code work fine but second not.can you tel me what's different between these code?

Comment: Is it because you're using same variable name `$linkGrabber;`?

Comment: ...the first one has a `:` at the end of the `<strong>` tag? How are you using this in your solution? This seems rather over-complicated for just grabbing data from a `<p>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say, they both work fine but they're named different. Make sure, when testing the second one to use $linkGrabber instead of $LinkGrabber in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever use Regex to Parse HTML tags. Make use of a DOM Parser.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html); //<---- Pass your HTML source here
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $tag) {
            echo $tag->nodeValue; //"prints" the content of the p tag.
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first is looking for HTML tags that contains `item1:` while the second looks for `item2`...